# Несколько контроллеров

Tags: php, laravel

Добрый вечер! Мне нужно сделать несколько вариантов вытяжки из базы. То есть пользователь выбирает по какому критерию сортировать(логин, почта, id и тд). Нужно сделать это на laravel. Собственно вопрос в том, как мне подключить несколько контроллеров к одной view? Не хочется делать для каждого варианта сортировки отдельную страницу

Comment: ОДИН контроллер обрабатывает вашу страницу. Традиционно запросы к БД происходят в МОДЕЛЯХ. В контроллерах можно подключать сколько угодно моделей раз уж у вас такая логика приложения.

Comment: Можно передавать на view несколько переменных в качестве `return` одного из методов контроллера

Answer (score 0):

Вам нет нужды подключать несколько Controllers для решения вашего вопроса. Контроллер отвечает за обработку запросов.

В данном случае, насколько я понял, перед вами стоит задача вывода на странице разных сущностей в зависимости от того, какие параметры передал пользователь.

Соответственно, в нужном методе контроллера вы проверяете введенные пользователем параметры, и в зависимости от них решаете, с какой из моделей (или несколькими сразу) вы будете работать. Далее полученные из моделей данные передаете в ваш view.